# Passing SET variable to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I think this is pretty straight forward, however my experience with SP's is quite limited.

I have a fairly lengthy query that I'm now trying to pass into a SP, I haven't had much luck so I'm breaking it down into sections and I'm stuck on the following part:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Exchange Rate] (@CCY char (3))

EXEC('

DECLARE @CurConv float

SET @CurConv = (Select XRATE FROM CURRENCY.dbo.currfx where CODE = ' + @CCY + ')

') END
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'GBP'.
```

The problem is GBP is not a column its a value? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the Database type?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql?

Comment: Because I'm passing the results into Excel

Answer (score 4):

Your dynamic query being executed is

```
SET @CurConv = (Select XRATE FROM CURRENCY.dbo.currfx where CODE = GBP
```

But is should be

```
SET @CurConv = (Select XRATE FROM CURRENCY.dbo.currfx where CODE = 'GBP'
```

So you have to surround value of `@CCY` with additional single quotes:

```
EXEC('

DECLARE @CurConv float

SET @CurConv = (Select XRATE FROM CURRENCY.dbo.currfx where CODE = ''' + @CCY + ''')

') END
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @CurConv float
Select @CurConv = XRATE FROM CURRENCY.dbo.currfx where CODE = @CCY

EXEC Exchange @CurConv